# Is it possible to use Rstudio to translate from .Rmd to LaTeX directly without pandoc?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, rstudio, pandoc

Reproducible example (if you have rstudio):

- File | New | R Markdown
- Knit to html, saving as `test` :

[image: knitr]

Navigate to working directory

- In a terminal (with pandoc installed) type

  pandoc -s test.md -t latex -o test.tex

(results pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/Qz5jhAxH))

- Convert to pdf with pdflatex (see result [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15008199/egs2stay/test.pdf))

Or skip the tex stage by going directly to .pdf:

```
pandoc -s test.md -t latex -o test2.pdf
```

The results are good, but seem like a lot of steps given that knitr incorporates sweave. It should be able to convert from .Rmd to .tex or .pdf directly. Right?

Comment: Of course "is it possible".  Has something written such a new converter which skips one or more steps of an existing tool pipeline?  Unsure, to unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for this - maybe a feature request for RStudio developers: add a "knit to LaTeX" button to reduce fiddle. Seems compatible with their philosophy http://www.rstudio.com/training/philosophy.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is documented in http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering; you should add an .Rprofile to your directory, for example:

```
options(rstudio.markdownToHTML = 
  function(inputFile, outputFile) {      
    system(paste("pandoc", shQuote(inputFile), "-o", shQuote(outputFile)))
  }
)
```

Some modifications might be necessary. Too bad the same does not work with spin because of a bug in RStudio.

http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/4128-spin-and-rprofile

Comment: this is a nice answer.  It seems to do what the OP wanted, although it's not technically "without pandoc" (e.g. if someone who hadn't/couldn't install[ed] pandoc wanted to do this), rather it's "without an additional annoying manual invocation of pandoc".

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles upon this old question, there is now (has been for a while) a `keep_tex: true` parameter that preserves the intermediate .tex file created  by Pandoc. Call it like this in the YAML header:

```yaml
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---
```